# что я делаю не так? нужно написать функцию в js которая перебирает массив объектов и в зависимости от условия if else возвращает массив значений

Tags: javascript

Мне надо чтобы функция возвращала в зависимости от значения `propName` массив значений ключей: `name, price ,quantity`, а вместо этого возвращается только одно значение. у меня дело в том что чат бот выдает условия задачи и мне надо дописать функцию

```
const products = [{
    name: 'Радар', price: 1300, quantity: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'Сканер', price: 2700, quantity: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'Дроид', price: 400, quantity: 7
  },
  {
    name: 'Захват', price: 1200, quantity: 9
  }];
  
function getAllPropValues(propName) {
  
// Пиши код ниже этой строки
  
    //вот тело функции:
    
    let name = []
    let price = []
    let quantity = []
    for (a of products) {
      if (propName = name) {
        name.push(a.name)
        continue
    
      }
      if (propName = price) {
        price.push(a.price)
        continue
      } if  (propName = quantity) {
        quantity.push(a.quantity)
        continue
      }
    }
    return propName

// Пиши код выше этой строки

}
```

Comment: что такое  propName ? И почему вы его сравниваете с массивами?

Comment: `=` - Это присваивание, `==` - это сравнение. Сейчас все добавляется только в массив `name`

Comment: обновил условие, теперь более понятно я надеюсь, у меня все нормально шло, а тут я уже 4 день не могу решить простую задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'Радар', price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'Сканер', price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'Дроид', price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: 'Захват', price: 1200, quantity: 9 }
];
  
function getAllPropValues(propName) {
  return (!products.length || !(propName in products[0]))? 
    [] : products.map(i => i[propName]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getAllPropValues('name')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getAllPropValues('price')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getAllPropValues('quantity')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getAllPropValues('noproperty')));
```

Comment: слушайте, это прекрасное решение, я правда не учил еще такой синтаксис, но тем не менее он работает и чат бот пропускает!☺️ единственный момент: не выполняется последние условие задачи: Вызов getAllPropValues('category') возвращает []. то есть должен вернуть пустой массив, если мы задаем массив ключей, которого нету, как здесь быть, посоветуйте

Answer (score 0):

1. Почитайте про [операторы сравнения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) не стоит путать их с [оператором присваивания](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) (одинарным равно) Вам же Grundy написал комментарий про это. В `if` не пишите оператор присваивания, сравнивайте свойства!
2. Вам надо возвращать массив, так возвращайте [массив](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays), а не то, что изначально передали в [функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)!

Comment: послушайте, если бы все было так просто, я не писал, я специально еще раз( уже не единожды игрался с операторами сравнения) - в моем случае чат бот выдает прохождение только одной итерации (к примеру массив значений ключей name с price уже не работает). если я ставлю два или три === функция вообще ничего не возвращает

Comment: дайте кто-нибудь почту - я скину скрины, может так понятней будет, ибо ситуация уже смешная))

Comment: @SerhiiKolechko Она ничего не возвращает, потому, что в функцию вы передаете строку и сравнивайте ее с пустым массивом))

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо проще:

```
function getAllPropValues(propName) {
  let valueArray = [];
   
  for (const product of products) {
    if (product.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
      valueArray.push(product[propName]);
    }
  }
  return valueArray;
}
```